# Compare value of specific column and add a value to another | Pandas | Python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, compare

I have a dataframe with 6 columns like that:

```
c1      c2             c3      c4           c5      c6
C875    DOID_3263       1       9.65E-18    1       unknown
C783    DOID_4064       1       4.80E-17    1       unknown
C372    DOID_0050084    0.996   0.00429     0.996   unknown
C43     DOID_936        0.0457  0.954       0.954   known
```

Column `c5` represent the max value between `c3 and c4`, I want to add a column `after c6` to compare if the max value in `c5` come from `c3 put 0` if it come from `c4 put 1`

So, at the end the final result will be like this:

```
c1      c2              c3      c4          c5      c6       c7
C875    DOID_3263       1       9.65E-18    1       known    0
C783    DOID_4064       1       4.80E-17    1       unknown  0
C372    DOID_0050084    0.996   0.00429     0.996   unknown  0
C43     DOID_936        0.0457  0.954       0.954   known    1
```

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

First, take the max of the two columns

```
df['c5'] = np.maximum(df['c3'], df['c4'])
```

If the max is equal to 'c4' put a 1, else 0 (which implies it came from 'c3' under this paradigm).

```
df['c7'] = (df['c5'] == df['c4']).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) yields the name of the columns right away

```
df[['c3','c4']].idxmax(1)

0    c3
1    c3
2    c3
3    c4
dtype: object
```

Can always map if need `0` or `1`

```
df[['c3','c4']].idxmax(1).map({'c3': 0, 'c4':1})

0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Nice solution, I had no idea idmax could be used in this fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Using `select` from `numpy`

```
s1=df.c3==df.c5
s2=df.c4==df.c5
df['c7']=np.select([s1,s2],[0,1])
df
Out[670]: 
     c1            c2      c3            c4     c5       c6  c7
0  C875     DOID_3263  1.0000  9.650000e-18  1.000  unknown   0
1  C783     DOID_4064  1.0000  4.800000e-17  1.000  unknown   0
2  C372  DOID_0050084  0.9960  4.290000e-03  0.996  unknown   0
3   C43      DOID_936  0.0457  9.540000e-01  0.954    known   1
```